# Ubuntu 16.04.1 install failed due to mount

Tags: 16.04, server, mount, virtualbox

Full log is [here](https://gist.github.com/wenerme/b34e5cf206c3fac904cb27bc541fd615)

```
Jan  3 06:04:58 kernel: [  101.232935] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
Jan  3 06:04:58 kernel: [  101.232981] work still pending
Jan  3 06:04:58 preseed: successfully loaded preseed file from file:///cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: (process:7002): mount: mounting /dev/sda on /media failed: Invalid argument
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: (process:7002): umount: can't umount /media: Invalid argument
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: (process:7002): mount: mounting /dev/sda on /media failed: Invalid argument
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: (process:7002): mount: mounting /dev/sda on /media failed: Invalid argument
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: (process:7002): umount: can't umount /media: Invalid argument
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: (process:7002): mount: mounting /dev/sda on /media failed: Invalid argument
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: (process:7002): mount: mounting /dev/fd0 on /media failed: No such file or directory
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: (process:7002): umount: can't umount /media: Invalid argument
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: (process:7002): mount: mounting /dev/fd0 on /media failed: No such file or directory
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
Jan  3 06:04:58 main-menu[603]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
```

What should I do ?

I tried install on vbox and a phy server, same error.

Comment: What is the host operating system, where you try to run Ubuntu in VirtualBox? Did you set the virtual machine for linux (Ubuntu)? Did you create a virtual disk? - Does Ubuntu boot and run well from the iso file (seen as a DVD disk)?

Comment: Mac OSX, Ubuntu 64bit, 20GB VDI. ISO DVD. I move back to 16.04, works fine.

Comment: So 16.04 LTS works well but not 16.04.1 LTS? This is opposite to most cases (with real hardware). What happens if you install 16.04 LTS and after that update and upgrade it to be up to date? - This would be a way to get [almost] the same system as if you start from the 16.04.1 LTS iso file.